# Find matching value in a row and return column name?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a sample price and I want to find the company that offers the lowest or an equal price to that sample price in the same row and put their name in the "Company Name" column. I tried to use IF to compare and but it results in "Too many arguments" error with large table. Can anybody tell me how to achieve it?

```
Price   Company A   Company B   Company C    Company Name
5       5           6           7           Company A
3       9           3           8           Company B
```

Comment: Please share your code (edit your original post and add it), it may be easier to fix that instead of coming up with new ways.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, lets go.  Your question says "lowest or equal" to the sample price, but don't say what to do if the price is greater than the sample price.  So I am just going with the lowest:

This finds the lowest price (I am assuming the company columns are B-D):

```
=min(B2:d2)            (equals 5 for your first row)
```

This finds the column position of the lowest price:

```
=match(min(b2:d2), b2:d2,0)      (equals 2 because that is the position of the lowest (5) in your first row)
```

This returns the value within the first row that has the column with the lowest value:

```
=index(b$1:d$1 ,match(min(b2:d2), b2:d2,0)))     (returns "Company A" - the contents of that cell)
```

So the last formula is all you need, the previous steps are just to explain how we got there.

Comment: No problem with the MATCH part but better to use INDEX to then get the value from top row, i.e. `=INDEX(B$1:D$1,MATCH(MIN(B2:D2),B2:D2,0))`

Comment: Oh yeah, much cleaner.  Feel free to edit it into the answer.

Comment: What an excellent solution! Thank you very much for your help, that's exactly what I need.