# Find matching value in a row and return column name II

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-spreadsheets

My qeustion is similar to, but different from [Find matching value in a row and return column name?](https://superuser.com/questions/522465/find-matching-value-in-a-row-and-return-column-name)

I have a spreadsheet with two tabs:

1. Tab A has one column which is a list of email addresses (there are many other columns in this tab)
2. Tab B has 4 columns, each of which has email addresses from different groups.  Each column has unique email addresses (no dupes between columns).  So Group 1 has 50 emails in Column A, and Group 2 has 100 emails in Column B, etc.

I would like to insert a formula into a new column in Tab A, which looks to the emails in each of the 4 columns in Tab B and compares them to the email address in Tab A.  If a match is found, write the column header.

Thanks so much for any help >;-)  I'm open to any ideas on how to set this up different to make it easier....

Comment: Are you doing this in Excel or Google Spreadsheets?

Answer (score 2):

And you can have an even shorter one with `SUMPRODUCT`:

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!$A$1:$D$1,SUMPRODUCT((A2=Sheet2!$A:$D)*1*{1,2,3,4}))
```

And I also noticed that if no matches are found (just like with the other formulae posted before this answer), it will return the column index of that of the formula itself (i.e. if the formula is in column B, it will return the name of the column B header). One way to avoid this is to use `IF` as so:

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!$A$1:$D$1,IF(SUMPRODUCT((A2=Sheet2!A2:D8)*1)=0,NA(),SUMPRODUCT((A2=Sheet2!A2:D8)*1*{1,2,3,4})))
```

It's a little bit longer ^^;

Comment: +1 Nice! (need more text for the comment)

Answer (score 1):

The following array formula should work. Enter it into the row 2 cell of the new column in Tab A, and then copy it down to the bottom of the Tab A list of emails.

```
  =INDEX(Sheet2!$A$1:$D$1,1,SUM((A2=Sheet2!$A$2:$A$50)*1+(A2=Sheet2!$B$2:$B$100)*2+(A2=Sheet2!$C$2:$C$50)*3+(A2=Sheet2!$D$2:$D$50)*4))
```

As an array formula, it needs to be entered with the <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd> key combination.

To break down the parts of the formula, assume for a moment that there is only one column of email data in Tab B, e.g., column A:

- `$A2=Sheet2!$A$2:$A$50` compares the email in cell A2 of Tab A with all the emails in column B of  Tab B, producing an array of match results such as `{False,True,False...False}`. Because the emails in Tab B are unique, there can be at most 1 `True` in the array.
- Next, that array is multiplied by 1 - `($A2=Sheet2!$A$2:$A$50)*1` - to produce another array '{0,1,0...0}', which can be interpreted as "The value in A2 is a match with the value in the second row of the data range in the first column of Tab B.
- Summing that array produces the value 1, which is used to pick out the value in the first column of the header row of Tab B: `INDEX($A$1:$D$1,1,SUM(($A2=Sheet2!$A$2:$A$50)*1))`.
- We can do the same array comparison with columns B, C, and D of Tab B, multiplying the results by 2, 3, and 4, respectively, to signify a match in the second, third, etc. column of Tab B.

Comment: Chuff, Thanks so much!  I ended up using a vlookup function that seems to have worked better for me, after I just collapsed those 4 email columns into a single column, and added a second column which contained the group name.  Again I really appreciate it!

Comment: +1. Also, any reason why only column B has range of rows from 2:100? :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also do that with a no-array formula, using Countif() instead of A2=Range:

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!$A$1:$D$1,(COUNTIF(Sheet2!$A:$A,Sheet1!$A2)*1)+(COUNTIF(Sheet2!$B:$B,Sheet1!A2)*2)+(COUNTIF(Sheet2!$C:$C,Sheet1!A2)*3)+(COUNTIF(Sheet2!$D:$D,Sheet1!A2)*4))
```

Comment: +1 Works as well and without arrays!